# Customize ContactPicker UI in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontact

How do I customize the UI of the CNContactPickerViewController?

I want to alter the colors, fonts, and text - similar to how snapchat has done?

[image]

Currently - my CNContactPickerViewController looks exactly like Apple's native contacts app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get contacts from address book and pass them into an `NSArray`:

```
CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSError *fetchError;
    CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:@[CNContactIdentifierKey, [CNContactFormatter descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle:CNContactFormatterStyleFullName]]];

    BOOL success = [store enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError usingBlock:^(CNContact *contact, BOOL *stop) {
        [contacts addObject:contact];
    }];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"error = %@", fetchError);
    }
}];
```

Then simply use the `NSArray` in a `UITableView` and from there you can customize the font, colors, etc.